# error CS0246, no se encuentra IWebHostEnvironment

Tags: c#, dotnetcore

Tengo un servicio en linux (centos 8), el cual realiza una tarea x de forma periódica, para lo cual implemente un servicio linux a través de systemd.
El programa funciona correctamente, salvo por un detalle, el cual momentáneamente solucione con "hard code"

En concreto, estoy tratando de obtener el directorio de la app, con  la siguiente linea de código

```
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _path = $"{hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath}ejtoAgente.log";
```

Lo cual me arroja el error en la interface **IWebHostEnvironment**, ya que no me la reconoce (estoy usando vscode)

según entiendo, el namespace necesario es Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, el cual tengo declarado en el inicio, y ademas  esta especificado en el archivo de definición del proyecto

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?
Saludos y gracias por leer

Answer (score 0):

ME FALTABA ESTA ESPECIFICACION EL EL PROYECTO

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.1" />
```